# XSLT for each (group?) with sorted two elements named as Code and Value

Tags: xml, xslt, xfdf

i need to transfer file xml to xfdf. And I have group with two element types code and value. Code is defining name of field and value is value of field. XML source is like this:

```
 <urn:identifications>
  <urn:identificationCode>dateOfBirth</urn:identificationCode>
  <urn:identificationValue>25021965</urn:identificationValue>
  <urn:identificationCode>ičdph</urn:identificationCode>     <!-- IC DPH -->
  <urn:identificationValue>1234567890</urn:identificationValue>
  <urn:identificationCode>ičo_sk</urn:identificationCode>      <!-- ICO (SK) -->
  <urn:identificationValue>0987654333</urn:identificationValue>
  <urn:identificationCode>ic</urn:identificationCode>      <!-- ICO (CZ) -->
  <urn:identificationValue>0987654321</urn:identificationValue>
  ...
</urn:identifications>
```

And I need something like this by XSLT to XFDF.

```
<identifications>
 <field name="dateOfBirth">
   <value>25021965</value>
 </field>
 <field name="ičdph">
   <value>1234567890</value>
 </field>
 <field name="ičo_sk">
   <value>0987654333</value>
 </field>
 <field name="ic">
   <value>0987654321</value>
 </field>
  ...
</identifications>
```

What I need to use? How? for-each-group? or som sets? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they always come in ordered pairs as shown in your example, then you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="urn:identifications">
    <identifications>
        <xsl:for-each select="urn:identificationCode">
            <field name="{.}">
                <value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::urn:identificationValue[1]"/>
                </value>
            </field>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </identifications>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Working. Thank you ! :)